# Почему прилетает два раза один и тот же пакет через ajax?

Tags: ajax, json

Вопрос чисто в образовательных целях, это не проблема.
При обработке `onreadystatechange` приходят 3 пакета (если я правильно понимаю, `responseText` - именно там хранится текст пакетов в представительном виде).
Первый пустой (**почему?**, кстати).
Второй выводит уже весь *artworks.json*.
Третий выводит то же самое, что и второй (**почему?**).
Может дело в json? А ещё на ум приходит такая штука, как контрольный пакет (не знаю, откуда я о таком знаю). Прошу разъяснить, что происходит тут)

Вот моя функция, которая совершает ajax:

```
function artAjaxRequest(pageSrc)
{
    var artworks;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/artworks/artworks.json', true);
    xhr.send();

    xhr.onload = function(){
        artworks = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    };

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        alert(this.responseText);
    };

    return function()
    {
        // Заглушка
    };
}
```

Чисто для справки сам *artworks.json*:

```
{
  "sketches": [
    {
      "title": "какой-то тайтл 1-го арта",
      "description": "какое-то описание 1-го",
      "date": "23.02.2017 19:42",
      "src": "1.png"
    },
    {
      "title": "какой-то тайтл 2-го арта",
      "description": "какое-то описание 1-го арта",
      "date": "23.02.2017 19:43",
      "src": "2.png"
    },
    {
      "title": "какой-то тайтл 3-го арта",
      "description": "какое-то описание 1-го арта",
      "date": "23.02.2017 19:43",
      "src": "3.png"
    }
  ],
  "somethingserious": [
    {
      "title": "какой-то тайтл 3-го арта",
      "description": "какое-то описание 1-го арта",
      "date": "23.02.2017 19:44",
      "src": "1.png"
    },
    {
      "title": "какой-то тайтл 3-го арта",
      "description": "какое-то описание 1-го арта",
      "date": "23.02.2017 19:44",
      "src": "2.png"
    },
    {
      "title": "какой-то тайтл 3-го арта",
      "description": "какое-то описание 1-го арта",
      "date": "23.02.2017 19:41",
      "src": "3.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Давайте почитаем [спецификацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange):

> Обработчик события (EventHandler), который вызывается всякий раз,
>   когда изменяется состояние свойства readyState. Свойство
>   XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange содержит обработчик события,
>   вызываемый когда происходит событие readystatechange, всякий раз 
>   когда свойство readyState запроса XMLHttpRequest **изменяется**. Функция
>   обратного вызова запускается из потока пользовательского интерфейса.

Другими словами, вы ждете от этого обработчика, что он будет вызван только тогда, когда запрос окажется успешным, а на самом деле он срабатывает каждый раз, когда у вас меняется состояние объекта `xhr`, а точнее его свойства `readyState`, что в целом одно и то же в вашем случае. Обратите внимание на пример кода по той же ссылке:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    method = "GET",
    url = "https://developer.mozilla.org/";

xhr.open(method, url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        };
    };
xhr.send();
```

Особенно на то, что проверяется во условии, а именно `xhr.readyState` и `xhr.status`. Только проверив эти два момента указанным выше способом, вы получите нужный вам код.

Другими словами, три раза у вас происходит срабатывание потому, что:

```
// первый раз вы просто создаете объект, именно тут обработчик дает вам пустой ответ
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// тут у вас есть уже json
xhr.open('GET', '/artworks/artworks.json', true);
// и тут у вас опять же есть уже json
xhr.send();
```

Возможно, я не совсем верно трактую происходящее в вашем коде, и событие вызывается иначе, но вообще очень похоже именно на то. Но то, что написано выше про проверку статуса и завершенности запроса - это в целом именно тот ответ, который вы ищете.

Comment: как может "// первый раз вы просто создаете объект, именно тут обработчик дает вам пустой ответ", если обработчик `onreadystatechange ` еще не назначен?

Comment: Это совершенно не тот ответ на вопрос, который я задавал.
 Я спросил: почему первый пакет пустой, а третий повторояет содержимое второго? Я не (!) спрашивал, как сделать так, чтобы он не выводил результат запроса три раза. Ты бегло прочел вопрос и ответил совершенно не то.

Comment: @VostokSisters про какой пакет речь? Я верно понял, что речь про то, что выводит alert?

Comment: Как сделать исполнение скрипта по успешному завершению запроса я знаю. И кстати, это делается не этим способом. Для успешного окончательного выполнения запроса придумали обработчик, он называется `onload`, смотри в той же спецификации, в которой я о нем и узнал.

Comment: @Станислав, да, речь про то, что выводит алерт. Но вопрос не про то, что он выводит результат 3 раза и как это исправить, а  почему первый пакет пустой, а третий повторояет содержимое второго?

Comment: @Igor, вы уверены, что он еще не назначен? Объект создается и в момент, когда он создан, `readyState` изменяется. Прочтите, что написано в документации еще раз: ==Свойство XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange содержит обработчик события, вызываемый когда происходит событие readystatechange, **всякий раз  когда свойство readyState** запроса XMLHttpRequest изменяется==

Comment: @VostokSisters, прочитайте мой предыдущий комментарий тут для Igor

Comment: @VostokSisters что же касается правильного или неправильного обработчика, то в примере просто показано, как сделать на основании такого варианта по факту тот же onload

Comment: @Станислав, ты не понял вопроса совершенно, к сожалению.

Comment: @VostokSisters ну, дело ваше, конечно